# Boot to external monitor in a broken screen and no operating systems installed

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, operating-systems, asus-laptop, lcd

So I have an **Asus EEE pc 1011ha** which I used occasionally. But as a year passed its screen just died and it had no operating system installed since I just formatted it to reinstall windows so, with no operating system, a dead lcd is it possible to use an external monitor?
Or is it just doomed?

**Note:** I do have another Desktop computer so if the fix requires another computer it OK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should find a standard VGA port on the left side edge.

From page 1 - 8 of the manual - a picture of the device's left side:

[image]

> 2 - The 15-pin D-Sub monitor port supports a standard VGA-compatible
> device such as a monitor or projector to allow viewing on a larger
> external display.

[Eee PC User’s Manual for English Edition](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePC/1101HA/e4982_Eee_PC_1101_series.zip)